# What is wrong with this insert statement?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-insert, create-table

Given the following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Members(

email VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
password VARCHAR(20),
pref_game_genre VARCHAR(20)

)

CREATE TABLE Normal_Users(

email VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Members,
first_name VARCHAR(20),
last_name VARCHAR(20),
date_of_birth date,
age as (YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - YEAR(date_of_birth))
)
```

I am trying to execute the following insert statement:

```
 INSERT INTO Normal_Users VALUES('testemail@gmail.com', 'Adam', 'Robert', '05-04-1990')
```

But I am getting the following error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Normal_Us__email__74994623". The conflict occurred in database "DatabasesProject", table "dbo.Members", column 'email'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did u insert records for Members table?

Comment: In addition to the above correct answers, email is not a best practice choice for a primary key, as people will often change email addresses.

Comment: Not to mention, unless you are comparing while forcing `UPPER()` or `LOWER()` on both sides, `'testemail@gmail.com'` is not the same as `'TestEmail@Gmail.com'`. Should also mention you would want to ensure you are using `TRIM()` as well since one could contain extra whitespace the other doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to populate `Members` table first.

```
INSERT INTO Members(email) VALUES('testemail@gmail.com')
INSERT INTO Normal_Users VALUES('testemail@gmail.com', 'Adam', 'Robert', '05-04-1990')
```

Comment: Does the value `testemail@gmail.com` exist in `Members.email`?

Answer (score 0):

On Normal_Users you are setting email as the primary key AND foreign key.

A better solution is to set email only as foreign key and choose another as primary key (maybe a generated id).